# What exactly is the domain of an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

If we say have two spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a linear operator, $T:X\rightarrow Y$ and we know that $T$ is bounded on $C\subsetneq X$ and not bounded elsewhere (I know terminology tends to state "not necessarily bounded"). Then does the domain of $T$, $D(T)=X$ or does $D(T)=C$.

I.e. is the domain only the set on which $T$ is well defined?

Best.

To bring this to context, I am working on questions of spectral theory.
I have the resolvent $R_{\frac{1}{2}}$ of the shift operator $T:l^\infty\rightarrow l^\infty$
so $T_{\frac{1}{2}}=T-\frac{1}{2}I$,

where $R_\frac{1}{2}=T_{\frac{1}{2}}^{-1}=(T-\frac{1}{2})^{-1}=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2T)^k$

Now I know that $R_\frac{1}{2}$ is bounded if $u\in l^\infty$ such that $\|u\|_{l^\infty}\lt\frac{1}{2}$.

I also believe that the range of $T_\frac{1}{2}$ , $Ran(T_\frac{1}{2})=l^\infty$

So we must have that $R_\frac{1}{2}:l^\infty\rightarrow l^\infty$, but it is only well defined on $U=\{u\in l^\infty ,\|u\|\lt \frac{1}{2}\}$

So I thought $D(R_\frac{1}{2})=U$. I also know that $D(R_\frac{1}{2})$ is not dense in $l^\infty$.

Comment: what is $T$? right- or left-shift?

Comment: Right I believe, here $T((u_1,u_2,...))=(0,u_1,u_2,...)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain $D(A)$ of an operator $A:D(A)\subset X\to Y$, is the set of $x\in X$, for which $Ax$ is well-defined.

Assuming that $T$ is the right-shift operator in the following. One can prove that $T-\frac12I:l^\infty \to l^\infty$ is injective. Thus, $(T-\frac12I)^{-1}$ exists on $range(T-\frac12I)$, 
$$
D((T-\frac12I)^{-1})=range(T-\frac12I).
$$
The range of $range(T-\frac12I)$ is not equal to $l^\infty$: the constant sequence $(1,1,\dots)$ is not in the range.

Comment: Okay, this is very helpful, and with a little effort I think you can show that any constant sequence is not in the range, but is that non existence enough to show the range is not dense in $l^\infty$?

Comment: This is not enough. You have to prove the non-denseness separately. Right now have no idea how to do that. The standard approach, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58712/spectral-decomposition-of-the-shift-operator-on-ell-pn, seems to fail here, because $l^1$ is not isomorph to $(l^\infty)^*$.

Comment: Interesting, it would be sufficient to show for instance that $(1,1,1,....)$ is not a limit point of the range?